# Create external table from csv on HDFS , all values come with quotes

Tags: sql, impala

I have a csv file on HDFS and I am trying to create an impala table , the situation is it created the table and values with all the "

```
CREATE external TABLE abc.def
(

name STRING,
title STRING,
last  STRING, 
pno STRING
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','

location 'hdfs:pathlocation'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1") ;
```

The output is
name tile last pno
"abc" "mr" "xyz" "1234"
"rew" "ms" "pre" "654"

I just want to create table from csv file without quotes. Please guide where I am going wrong. 
Regards, 
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do that is creating a stage table that load the file with quotes and then with CTAS (Create table as select) create the right table cleaning the fields with replace function.
As an example

```
CREATE TABLE quote_stage(
 id STRING,
 name STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | name     |
+-----+----------+
| "1" | "pepe"   |
| "2" | "ana"    |
| "3" | "maria"  |
| "4" | "ramon"  |
| "5" | "lucia"  |
| "6" | "carmen" |
| "7" | "alicia" |
| "8" | "pedro"  |
+-----+----------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE t_quote 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
AS SELECT replace(id,'"','') AS id, replace(name,'"','') AS name FROM quote_stage;
```

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | pepe   |
| 2  | ana    |
| 3  | maria  |
| 4  | ramon  |
| 5  | lucia  |
| 6  | carmen |
| 7  | alicia |
| 8  | pedro  |
+----+--------+
```

Hope this helps.